# Custom taxonomy for woocomerce products

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I'm creating a custom taxonomy named brands for my products. I created a taxonomy brands and it's showing in my products,but how to display brands in my shop page and home page ?please help me  .I have used acf to add a field  brand images and i want to call my brand image in my home page

Answer (score 0):

As per plugin documentation, you can get your taxonomy image like this...

```
 // get value from a taxonomy (taxonomy = "brands", term_id = 3)
 $value = get_field('field_name', 'brands_3');
```